# ArgoCD fails to resolve host.minikube.internal

Tags: minikube, argocd

I have successfully install a Helm chart from http://host.minikube.internal:8880/charts. But the status is Progressing and Synced.

Upon checking the log of repo-server. I found this:

```
repo-server time="2024-01-05T23:15:52Z" level=warning msg="Could not get hostname for repository 'http://host.minikube.internal:8880/charts'"
```

It seems at some steps, it fails to recognize the hostname. This could also contribute to the failure in deploying app from a Git repo instead of Helm chart with ArgoCD. Where it looks synced and healthy, yet no related service or pod are deployed (only the namespaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArgoCD doesn't support Helm chart using http as mentioned in its code here https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/40760eb8528766745328e67e124e2cf1f56d8d93/pkg/apis/application/v1alpha1/repository_types.go#L239

Use either https or oci protocol

Another thing is, please ensure that Application objects are deployed on the namespace where ArgoCD is installed which is usually argocd. Otherwise, no pod will ever be deployed!